# unknown type given number but casted as string acts as a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following code.

```
let myVar = unknown;
myVar = 5;
console.log((myVar as string) + 5);
```

This code's output is 10. However, when we add string and number it should concatenate two. In this particular scenario I thought I would get 55;
Could someone clear my misunderstanding?

Comment: can you add below line before `console.log` and let us know the output?

`myVar = myVar as string`

Comment: `as` is called a type assertion, not a cast or conversion. You're essentially telling the compiler to trust you; that you know the type is string at this point and time. If you want to convert it, you need to do it the old regular JavaScript way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript compiles to javascript, javascript does not have types. So your code compiles to:

```
let myVar;
myVar = 5;
console.log(myVar + 5);
```

And `5 + 5` is `10`.

You assign a number, then add a number to that, and you get back a number.

---

`unknown` is a type that accepts any value, but can't be narrowed to a more specific type until you assert or validate it as something. This process does not change the value, just the typescript compilers understanding of the type.

There are two ways to get something useful from `unknown`.

You can test the value like:

```
if (typeof myVar === 'number') myVar // myVar is number here
if (typeof myVar === 'string') myVar // myVar is string here
```

Or you can use a type assertion to override the compiler with `as`, which is what you did in your example. Doing this provides no type safety, and should be avoided.